# Graph two different Data sets in same column

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, graphing

I have data that I need to compare but the values of two different groups are in the same column (and not in order of group).

For example:

```
Price     Group    
1.0        S
2.5        N
0.00       N
3.00       S
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple ideas:

```
GroupS = data[data$Group == "S",]
GroupN = data[data$Group == "N",]

split(data, data$Group)

ggplot(data, aes(<x-variable>, Price, color=Group)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I forgot to use a comma because I'm used to working with data.table and I sure didn't load the ggplot library. Can you explain to me how that's awkward?